# Using HistoryLocation in a client side react router app

Tags: reactjs, html5-history, react-router

I am setting up a purely client side react app using react router. The app needs to be static rather than run on a server, as I have to host it in S3.

In my `Router.run` I am trying to use HistoryLocation, but it does not seem to work. Is it not possible in client side only routing so I need to use HashLocation?

```jsx
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {  
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Looking at the react router documentation for [HistoryLocation](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#HistoryLocation):

*Uses the HTML5 history API to create real URLs. We recommend you use this location. It has better looking URLs and is required for picking up a server rendered app in the browser.*

*You must configure your server to use HistoryLocation*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support HistoryLocation, you won't be able to point requests directly at your S3 html resource. You'll need to put the resource behind an app server (node.js, rails), or a web server, e.g. nginx or apache, that is set up to return your static page at any of the routes you want to support on the client side.

The docs you refer to provide an example for express: http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#configuring-your-server

Here's an article that provides more info: http://www.staticapps.org/articles/routing-urls-in-static-apps